# Dont let the user Install an app if some other app is already on that device

Tags: android

Here is what I am trying to do. I want only those users to install my app with package name as `com.instance.partyhard` who doesnt have already installed an app with package name as  `com.example.abc`. FYI both are my apps but I dont want users to install both of my apps. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: No I dont think there is such way. If the two same application has different package name then they both are allow to install.

Comment: You can check if they have your other app installed when they launch this app, but I don't know if that will solve your issue

Comment: no, they are not same apps they are completely different. but I want to communicate between these two apps and I dont want user to install both of them , So I just want to put a check at the time of installation of the app.

Answer (score 1):

At Installation Time you cannot check which Apps are already installed. This would be a privacy lag an security problem.

You could check for installed apps on the startup of your app and display a note (or open an Intent to start the other app) to inform the user to use the other app.